# CURL Selenium Commands Not Returning Session ID

Tags: selenium, curl, selenium-webdriver, automation, selenium-chromedriver

I'm using Win10 & my CURL is installed in my C drive. 
My chromedriver.exe is placed in "Drivers" folder in my C Drive.

I launched CMD & typed: cd C:\Drivers which took me to my Drivers folder. Then i typed:

```
         .\chromedriver.exe
```

ChromeDriver was running & i got 9515 as the port number.

Now i opened another CMD & typed: cd  C:\Drivers to visit the drivers folder again. 
Then i typed:

**curl -XPOST http://localhost:9515/session -d '{"desiredCapabilities":{"browserName":"chrome"}}'**

I received the below JSON Response:

{"value":{"error":"invalid argument","message":"invalid argument: missing command parameters","stacktrace":"Backtrace:\n\tOrdinal0 [0x00B1A113+1548563]\n\tOrdinal0 [0x00A9DDA1+1039777]\n\tOrdinal0 [0x00A1E485+517253]\n\tOrdinal0 [0x009C7FDA+163802]\n\tOrdinal0 [0x009C7CAA+162986]\n\tOrdinal0 [0x009A221E+8734]\n\tOrdinal0 [0x009A2606+9734]\n\tOrdinal0 [0x009A2C80+11392]\n\tOrdinal0 [0x00AB71B7+1143223]\n\tGetHandleVerifier [0x00BB2B46+507814]\n\tGetHandleVerifier [0x00BB2864+507076]\n\tGetHandleVerifier [0x00BB9F47+537511]\n\tGetHandleVerifier [0x00BB3402+510050]\n\tOrdinal0 [0x00AAF29C+1110684]\n\tOrdinal0 [0x009A204E+8270]\n\tOrdinal0 [0x009A1D99+7577]\n\tGetHandleVerifier [0x00E4DE3C+3240604]\n\tBaseThreadInitThunk [0x74C38484+36]\n\tRtlValidSecurityDescriptor [0x77222EC0+448]\n\tRtlValidSecurityDescriptor [0x77222E90+400]\n"}}

CLEARLY, THE SESSION_ID WAS NOT DISPLAYED IN THE RESPONSE.
ANY REASON WHY??

Comment: That message means the json you sent was wrong. There's supposed to be a parameters key.